# How do I get Word 2007 to stop adding an extra 0 to the end of a line when I save as a PDF?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2007

I have a Word document (DOCX) that has a line that ends with "2010". When I view and print the document with Word, everything is OK.

When I save as a PDF in Word 2007, a 0 is appended to the end of the line so that it appears as "20100". How do I get Word to stop adding an extra character?

Comment: It works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried opening the document.xml file with Visual Studio, removing the offending 0s, and inserting the missing 0 to the end of "201". When I opened the DOCX with Word, the line ended with "201" so the only solution I can think of now is to recreate the document from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Check for updates to MS-Office.  Sometimes finicky little problems like this are often resolved with some minor updates.

In the meantime, you always do have the option of using a print driver such as PDF Creator (which will let you generate a PDF from any application with the ability to print using a Windows printer):

PDF Creator
  http://www.pdfforge.org/